# ios - what is the conventional method to display errors and messages to the user?

Tags: ios, ios5

I am an Android user, and just learning ios so I am not too familiar with some of the UX details.

If an app has a form that needs a success message, or a message about a validation error, what is the conventional way of accomplishing this in ios?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conventional way of presenting success is to present nothing. You might refresh data or navigate with an animation, but mostly you should just get out of the way.

The conventional way of presenting errors easily is to use a [`UIAlertView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html), offering a clear, concise message on what went wrong and how to fix it if possible.

Don't constrain yourself to stock controls that make it easy, though. There are many other, gentler ways to indicate failure than a modal popover (which is what the alert view is). Take a look at Tweetbot. They use a non-modal banner view to indicate both success and failure, such as when the network can't be reached. This is an especially good idea if the error is transient, since it doesn't require user interaction to dismiss.

[image: CC-BY-SA image of Tweetbot error banner, by Flickr user Gustavo Pimenta]

Answer (score 3):

Validation errors are often done with a UIAlertView.

Success confirmations could be done with a "toaster" notification (as seen in Tweetbot's iPhone app, here: http://shawnblanc.net/images/tweetbot-notifications.jpg), though this would require custom code.

UIAlertViews could also be used for a success message, but since it's highly interrupting, it's probably not ideal.

Comment: thank you, so the toaster is a 3rd party library, correct?  Could I use the UIAlertView to display a positive message? Or is it just for errors?

Comment: When displaying a positive message try to place yourself in user's point of view: you can show it somewhere if you wish but don't force users to tap a button when something goes as it's supposed to (which would be the case in UIAlertView). UIAlertView should be displayed when something goes wrong... Maybe you could play a cheerful sound if operations succeedes or something.

Comment: I'm with @rokjarc on this - your app should not send confirmation messages constantly, since it would interrupt the user's next action. You could use a UIActivityIndicatorView to indicate progress, and when it stops spinning, the implication is that a task was completed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I used `UIAlertView` class.  Here is the link to [Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) on this class.